# Swift: Adding value to a statement

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, I hope it's not to late to edit my question. I realized my question didn't really help me for many reasons. Here's a better way to ask it.

How can I turn a function like this

```
let doc = db.collection("ReviewSchedule").document("\(userEmail ?? "Error")")
    doc.updateData([
        "Flight ": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(formateddateschedule)", "\(formatedstartschedule)", "\(formatedendschedule)"])
    ])
```

So that every time it runs, it adds 1 at the end of "Flight" so eventually, in firebase, there will be a list of arrays named Flight 1, Flight 2, Flight 3, Flight 4, Flight 5, Flight 6, etc... with the variables inside the array as in the code.

Basically, everytime this function runs, how can I add +1 to the previous value after the Flight text.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without an actual minimal, reproducible example, but it doesn't look like you are returning a view. `ForEach` has to return a view.

Comment: I updated my question because it didn't really help my problem. I'd rather do something like the updated question instead of using the ForEach.

Comment: Well obviously you'd need to keep a number stored somewhere. Each time this method is called, you'd increment the number and use it in the "Flight" key. It's hard to see what the difficulty is.

Comment: As already mentioned by @matt you have to store the number somewhere in your code and each time the method is invoked you have to increment it. After incrementing you can use it by appending to the `Flight` key. Can you mention what is the difficulty you are facing while doing it?

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't really understand how. I was stuck on an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime this function is run, I used:

```
ScheduledFlightNumber += 1
```

To add to an Int variable. Then set that variable into the name like so:

```
"Flight \(ScheduledFlightNumber)"
```